# Deleting data from database based on array using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to delete multiple items from a db based on the ID's which are stored in an array and being passed using AJAX

The array data is correct I just cannot figure out why the code below won't delete the records.

Any help really appreciated

My jQuery Code :

```
$("#bulkdel").click(function(){
event.preventDefault();
var idlist = $("#companylist input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
console.log(idlist);
var length = Object.keys(idlist).length
var count = 'There are '+length +' items selected';
var doDelete = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "dodelete.php",
  data: idlist,
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(resultData) { alert("Delete Complete") }
 });
```

Here is the PHP code :

```
session_start();
include('inc/config.php');
$ids = implode("','", $_POST['idlist']);
mysqli_query($dbc,"DELETE FROM `comp_companies` WHERE `company_id` IN ('".$ids."')");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `idlist` is an array, so you don't need to use `Object.keys` on it; just `idlist.length` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're sending the plain array in the request with no key, therefore `$_POST['idlist']` is undefined in your PHP.

To fix this just change the `data` attribute in your request:

```
var doDelete = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "dodelete.php",
  data: { idlist: idlist }, // note the object here
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(resultData) { 
    alert("Delete Complete") 
  }
});
```

Note that if you don't care about IE support you can use ES6 syntax for the object and just provide the variable in an object. The key name will then automatically be inferred:

```
data: { idlist }
```

```js
var idlist = [1, 2, 3];
console.log({ idlist })
```

Comment: Awesome ! Knew it was just something daft I was missing..
Do you know how I could refresh the table after the ajax callback ?
as it still displays the deleted rows

Comment: That would depend on how you loaded it, but you just need to call that logic again. Alternatively you could just call `remove()` on the row, but that may mess up your paging logic.

Comment: Rory how do I delete specific rows in the the success function ?
All I seem to be doing is removing the whole table

Comment: `$('table tbody tr:eq(rowIndexHere)').remove()`

Comment: sorry am new to javascript / jquery
I've tried $('table tbody tr:eq('+idlist+')').remove()
but that doesnt work

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your HTML and knowing where the `#bulkdel` element is within the structure. I'd suggest starting a new question about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179531/discussion-between-chris-yates-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: Cant post for another 90 mins, Have invited you to chat where I've posted a link to my PHP file ( have commented code so will be visible )